# OSX tries to finish an update after login, hangs at completion then shuts down

Tags: macos, software-update

Yesterday I restarted my MacBook Pro and it started installing updates after I logged in again. The problem is it does not complete. It fills up to 100 %, then hangs for like 10 minutes and ultimately shuts down. When I power on the MacBook Pro again the same happens cycle is about to take place.

I tried to reset the NVRAM and also to check the disk using <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. It seems I have DataVault enabled and I am also unable to unlock the drive. When I try to reinstall OS X/macOS – where I have already accepted data loss – I can not complete the task because of the locked drive. When I unlock the drive using my correct password, the main drive disappears.

I have tried to fire up the MacBook Pro in safe mode and also logged in as a guest user. The laptop just can not complete the login process for my user.

What can I do to resolve

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what happens when you try to unlock your partition in Disk Utility from the Recovery Partition. It won't accept your password? Did you check the keyboard layout is correct?

Comment: The main problem is that afer I login the laptop doesnt start. It tries to complete an update, but never completes and shuts down. Im trying to fix that in a way I can use my laptop again.

Comment: OK. But, it is not clear to me why you cannot reinstall macOS from the Recovery Partition. Why can't you unlock your macOS partition? What happens exactly?

Comment: When I unlock the partition it disappears from the selection list on which partition I want to reinstall. I've fixed it by entirely removing the partition, recreating a new one and reinstall OSX on that partition. Too bad my data is all gone, but most of it was in a cloud backup.